# How to change default dropdown color for bootstrap 4 selectpicker?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

My form is consists of single and multiple dropdown select. So I prefer to use 1 class only for my single and multiple which is `selectpicker`. However, I want to change the default grey color for Bootstrap 4 Dropdown `selectpicker` class to clear color. Where is exactly color that needs to be changed in CSS file for `.bootstrap-select` class?

**Current View** (actually this no disabled but the view is like disabled)
[image]

**To be like this** (I try to use `custom-select2` class as example of clear color)
[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="region" class="font-14 selectpicker form-control">
        <option value="">-- REGION --</option>
        <option value="allregions" id="allregions">All Regions</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I modify below code and solve my problem.

```
.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-toggle.bs-placeholder:active {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the color element.

The solution is `btn-light` in my case

```
.btn-light{
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this CSS:

```
.selectpicker{
background: #FFF;
color: #000;
}
```

Comment: I want using `selectpicker`, not `custom-select.

Comment: I have added above code in CSS file, but nothing changes.

Comment: I have find the solution.